# Is there a Ruby idiom for encapsulating an object in an Array if it isn't already?

Tags: ruby, xml, arrays, hash

I am working with an external API with which I'm exchanging XML messages. So I use a lot of `Hash#from_xml`.

However, `#from_xml` only encodes elements in an Array if they are repeating elements. It makes sense, but it breaks when I am trying to loop through a repeatable element that appears only once. For example:

```
<Stuff>
  <SKU>ABC-123</SKU>
  <SKU>DEF-456</SKU>
  <SKU>XYZ-789</SKU>
</Stuff>
```

works great, because:

```
my_hash = Hash.from_xml(xmlstring)["Stuff"]
```

will contain 3 SKUs, so I can do:

```
my_hash["Stuff"].each do |sku|
  # process the sku
end
```

But it fails with this XML:

```
<Stuff>
  <SKU>XYZ-789</SKU>
</Stuff>
```

because `myhash['SKU']` is a Hash, not an Array. I'm having to do this now:

```
my_hash['SKU'] = [my_hash['SKU']] if my_hash['SKU'].kind_of?(Hash)
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap it in an array and flatten it:

```
array_of_one_or_many = [my_hash['SKU']].flatten
```

If it's already an array it will unwrap it and make it a common array anyway. Works for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

When I've encountered this in the past, I've used

```
foo = ([] << bar).flatten
```

`bar` is the object and `foo` will be a flat array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array()`

```
irb(main):012:0> Array(1)
=> [1]
irb(main):013:0> Array([1])
=> [1]
```